# Issue on postgresql Parrot Security Use of uninitialized value $data_directory in concatenation (.)

Tags: postgresql

I'm using parrot on subsystem on windows 10.
Everything was installed right but postgresql don't start.

Log:

```
#sudo service postgresql restart
Use of ninitialized value $data_directory in concatenation (.) or string 
at /usr/share/perl5/PgCommon.pm line 211.
[....] Restarting PostgreSQL 11 database server: main[....] Use of 
uninitialized value $data_directory in concatenation (.) or string at 
/usr/share/perl5/PgCommon.pm line 211. Use of uninitialized value 
$info{"start"} in string eq at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 361. Use of 
uninitialized value $info{"pgdata"} in -d at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 
364. Use of uninitialized value $info{"pgdata"} in concatenation (.) or 
string at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 365. Error: is not acce[FAILe or 
does not exist ... failed!
failed!
```

How I can fix it?
Thank you very much.